# The local maxima of $\sin(n\phi/2)/\sin(\phi/2)$ for large $n$

Tags: calculus, analysis, trigonometry, physics

Let $n \in \mathbb N$ be given and $\phi\in (0,\pi)$ be some angle. Consider the function
$$
 \frac{\sin(n\phi/2)}{\sin(\phi/2)}.
$$
For very small $\phi$ , this function "approaches" the maximum $n^2$. But I do not understand the following argument, taken from [The Feynman Lectures, Volume I, chapter 30](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_30.html):

> Now we go to the next maximum, and we want to see that it is really much smaller than the first one, as we had hoped. We shall not go precisely to the maximum position, because both the numerator and the denominator of [the above formula] are variant, but $\sin\phi/2$ varies quite slowly compared with $\sin n\phi/2$ when $n$ is large, so when $\sin(n\phi/2) = 1$ we are very close to the maximum. The next maximum of $\sin^2(n\phi/2)$ comes at $n\phi/2 = 3\pi/2$, or $\phi = 3\pi/n$.

I do not understand why the next maximum comes for $\sin(n\phi/2) = 1$? As I see it, as $\sin(\phi/2)$ could take any value, the quotient could realise any value too, so some local maximum could be even before that point?

Comment: You do mean $\sin (n\phi/2)/\sin (\phi/2)$, not $\sin (n\phi)/\sin (\phi)$, right?

Comment: Is $n$ an integer or natural number? When I plot this, there are infinities when $n$ isn't an integer.

Comment: Thanks for the comments, I fixed both issues!

Answer (score 2):

You may be mixing up local and global maxima. Feynman's argument is that $\sin (\phi/2)$ varies slowly enough that it can be taken as essentially constant on intervals around the peaks of $\sin (n\phi/2)$, so the *local* extrema of $\sin (n\phi/2)/\sin (\phi/2)$ occur more or less at the same values of $\phi$ as the local extrema of $\sin (n\phi/2)$. Whether these local extrema are also *global* extrema, of course, depends on the value of $\sin (\phi/2)$ (as you correctly note).

Comment: Isn't that a very broad and vague approximation? I mean the interval must be very small to regard it constant...

Comment: ... or $n$ very large. Feynman is talking about large (quasi-infinite) diffraction gratings where $n$ is the number of slits, so the approximation makes sense.

Comment: Yes, but the point was he wanted to show that we have one strong maxima and the other ones are just very weak, but if this reasoning just applies around a tiny intervall around one strong maxima we might very well still have many different strong maximas and not just one single strong beam of radiation, as this is what he wanted to have if I got it right?